# Using LIKE CONCAT with wildcard

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the standard LAMP environment. I've taken an example directly from mysql.com website and adapted it to my table structure.

```
$sql = 'SELECT cat_name
FROM cats
WHERE cat_name LIKE concat('%', 'Artist', '%') ';
```

- But this does not work... the screen is just blank and even "view source" in the browser is blank

My issue is that, even though all of the examples I've found on StackOverflow and other forums use single quotes ('%') it only works if I use double quotes like this ("%").

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes as string delimiters for your sql string.

```
$sql = "SELECT cat_name
        FROM cats
        WHERE cat_name LIKE concat('%', 'Artist', '%')";
```

If you use the same string delimiter for both (your sql string and strings in your sql string)  then this will terminate your sql string before you want it.

Comment: That worked. I'm not sure why, as the single quotes works in all of the other examples I've tried. But I'm just happy that it worked! Thank you.

Comment: Look at your sql string in your question. See the color of the words. And look at the colors of my sql string. It is all dark red. If you understand why, you understand the problem.

Comment: I've got it now. Much appreciated!